# Apache2 - AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot does not exist

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2

I followed this guide to setup two virtual hosts under Apache.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

When restarting the Apache service I get the following warnings. Can someone please help me get rid of them?

When updating the A record to point to this server's IP the page cannot be displayed.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
* Restarting web server apache2                                                                                           
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/domain1.com.au/public_html] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/domain2.com/public_html] does not exist
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

Directory listing of /var/www/domain1.com.au:

```
drwxr-xr-x 7 webuser webuser 4.0K Nov 13 15:44 pubic_html
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look closely at the output - there is an error in your file name.
pubic_html vs. public_html

This may be an error. Correct this and restart apache.

Third one is not fatal, but you may want to look at ServerName variable for your virtual hosts and in global configuration file.